# FFMPEG output to the Exact Folder using Python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, compression, video-compression

i'm working on a simple script using ffmpeg, to reduce the size of a video and add watermark to the video, then move the final output into the compressed folder... this is my script.

the compression works, the watermark works, but the issue i'm having is that the final output is placed in the root folder, and not in the compressed folder...  below i my folder structure and my scripts

**Folder Structure**

```
   rootfolder
    |
    |--media
       |--vids
          |--(video files, mov, mp4s)..
       |--compressed
    |--encode.py
```

**Script (encode.py) file**

```
import os    
import subprocess
from pathlib import Path


dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))    
vidfile = dir_path + '/media/vids/mv1.mov'    
watermark = dir_path + '/media/watermark.png'
compressed = str(Path.cwd() / '/media/compressed/')

# 1. compress the video and store it in the media out folder

media_out = str(dir_path + "/compressed_mv1s.mov").replace(" ", "\\ ") 
subprocess.run("ffmpeg -i " + vidfile.replace(" ", "\\ ") +
               " -vcodec libx264 -crf 22 " + media_out, shell=True)  

#2.add watermark to the video and move it to the compressed folder 

media_watermarked = str(compressed + '/w_mv1.mov').replace(" ", "\\ ")
subprocess.run("ffmpeg -i " + media_out + " -i " + watermark +
               " -filter_complex \"overlay=main_w-(overlay_w+10) : main_h-(10+overlay_h)\" " + media_watermarked, shell=True)
```

in summary, compressing the video works, adding watermark works, but the last line, the error is from the `media_watermarked` variable,  i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong but it isn't resolving the folder correctly moving the final output to the folder..  this is the error i get

[image]

Also, how can i run two ffmpeg commands concurrently to compress the video and add watermark at once without doing it seperately.
Thanks.

Comment: `compressed = str(Path.cwd() / '/media/compressed/')` compressed has '/' at the end and `media_watermarked = str(compressed + '/w_mv1.mov')` here you are again appending a '/' after compressed string. That maybe a issue here?

Comment: Why do this in 2 ffmpeg commands instead of just 1? You can compress and watermark at the same time. It will be faster and you'll avoid additional [generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss).

Comment: @llogan, thats why i asked... if you have a solution on how i could combine both commands into one.

Comment: @AndeCaleb Simply add `-vcodec libx264 -crf 22` to your watermark command.